# postgresql disable modifying pg_hba to connect

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql 11 instance that need to share with the client, it's ok to let the client do whatever they want except the accounts.

if the client modifies the `pg_hba.conf`, they can connect without password, is there any way to disable `pg_hba`, making it no way to connect without password?

PS: the client has the host access

Comment: Don't let the client access the file. If they have host access, don't let them log in as `postgres`, give them their own (Linux AND Postgres) user

Comment: It's a good way, giving the client doesn't have full control of the host. However my situation is the client does have root privillege of the host, still thinking how to do that~